# Filling NA's with numeric order in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as below:

```
    LogdiffT    Year    Country
0   -0.003094   2002    Australia
1   -0.015327   2001    NaN
2   0.100617    2000    NaN
3   0.067728    1999    NaN
4   0.089962    2010    China
5   -0.041844   2009    NaN
6   -0.031013   2008    NaN
7   0.091948    2007    NaN
8   0.082764    2006    Greece
9   0.103519    2005    NaN
10  -0.048100   2004    NaN
11  -0.014992   2003    NaN
12  0.166187    1966    Japan
```

If you see all NA's under the country column and following a country name belongs to that country name until a new country name is encountered. Like all 3 NA's after Australia stand for Australis and the 3 NAs' after China stand for China and so on. I want to recode this variable as a numeric variable such that all observations which belong to one country are coded as same. Like all 4 obs for Australia(AUS+3NAs) should have 1, China as 2 and so on.

In SAS I can do order by and use first. and last. and recode. How do we do similar stuff in pandas.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried implementing one of below solution. And here is one interesting thing I am getting and am not sure why?

My data frame is as above. When I run this: 
df.Country or df['Country'] I get an error that there is no column called Country when there is;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-360-361952a0cbf3> in <module>()
      2 data_train=data_2yr[features] # Subsetting the features from original data
      3 # Recoding Country, Year variable
----> 4 data_train.Country

/Users/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1945                 return self[name]
   1946             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1947                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1948 
   1949     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Country'
```

Because of this I am not able to implement the solutions proposed. What is going wrong here?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Show output from `df.columns` you may have embedded spaces

Comment: Yes, you are right.  just checked and country column shows 'country '. How did that happen?. Right when I imported the sheet?. Any idea such pitfalls can be avoided or spaces removed from data frame column headers? Like something like .strip similar to string?

Comment: Btw, I removed the space in the excel file itself and then imported. So it worked now. However when I try your solution it does give me a warning:

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__main__.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Depends on how you loaded it, you could do `df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).str.replace(' ','')`, regarding your new warning, does it raise the warning if you run the command as 2 separate steps? so `df = df.fill()` and then df['Country'] = df['Countr'].factorize()[0]`?

Comment: Nopes. Separately running doesn't give error. Why?

Comment: It could be due to the chaining of the commands which is something it doesn't like, it's best to separate them to be absolutely sure it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `df = df.ffill()` and then call [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html#pandas.Series.factorize), `factorize` returns a tuple of array values and an index which is composed of your Series values, we only want the array values here:

```
In [476]:

df['Country'] = df['Country'].factorize()[0]
df
Out[476]:
    LogdiffT  Year  Country
0  -0.003094  2002        0
1  -0.015327  2001        0
2   0.100617  2000        0
3   0.067728  1999        0
4   0.089962  2010        1
5  -0.041844  2009        1
6  -0.031013  2008        1
7   0.091948  2007        1
8   0.082764  2006        2
9   0.103519  2005        2
10 -0.048100  2004        2
11 -0.014992  2003        2
12  0.166187  1966        3
```

output from `factorize`:

```
In [480]:

df['Country'].factorize()
Out[480]:
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]),
 Index(['Australia', 'China', 'Greece', 'Japan'], dtype='object'))
```

As suggest by @John Galt you could compact the above into a one-liner:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].ffill().factorize()[0]
```

Comment: Ah. `factorize()` @EdChum's answer is certainly better than mine +1.

Comment: Note: Before you apply `factorize()` you need to `fill` your `NaNs`

Comment: @JohnGalt yes you're right I think when I first tried this it seemed to work but I just tried again and it put `-1` for `NaN` values

Comment: A minor addition based on you solution a single liner could be `df['Country'].ffill().factorize()[0]`? Instead of applying `ffill()` on complete `df`

Comment: Yes that's true, I sometimes prefer to break the answer down as one-liner can be obfuscating

Comment: Oh.I didn't know  about ffill. I knew about factorise() though. But didn't know it could be so simple. Oh. When will I learn the pandas intricacies and come out of loop thinking. :(

Comment: Also I was thinking pf using np.where as if condition. But that was going pretty long. Imagine 12 such countries. So I was writing something like: 

df.country=np.where(df.country=="Australia",1,(np.where(df.country=="China",2,(np.where(df.country=="Japan",3… and so on.. but this was getting way long. Any idea how can someone do this using where/if concepts?

Comment: Please post another new question, it's counter-productive and unhelpful for others with similar needs if you keep incrementing the scope of your question, but yes I have an answer that too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it.

Get unique countries list by dropping NaNs

```
In [66]: country_dict = {y:x for x,y in enumerate(df['Country'].dropna().unique())}

In [67]: country_dict
Out[67]: {'Australia': 0, 'China': 1, 'Greece': 2, 'Japan': 3}
```

Replace `Country` with `country_dict`

```
In [68]: dff = df.replace({'Country': country_dict})

In [69]: dff
Out[69]:
    LogdiffT  Year  Country
0  -0.003094  2002        0
1  -0.015327  2001      NaN
2   0.100617  2000      NaN
3   0.067728  1999      NaN
4   0.089962  2010        1
5  -0.041844  2009      NaN
6  -0.031013  2008      NaN
7   0.091948  2007      NaN
8   0.082764  2006        2
9   0.103519  2005      NaN
10 -0.048100  2004      NaN
11 -0.014992  2003      NaN
12  0.166187  1966        3
```

And, then `ffill()` with previous values.

```
In [70]: dff.ffill()
Out[70]:
    LogdiffT  Year  Country
0  -0.003094  2002        0
1  -0.015327  2001        0
2   0.100617  2000        0
3   0.067728  1999        0
4   0.089962  2010        1
5  -0.041844  2009        1
6  -0.031013  2008        1
7   0.091948  2007        1
8   0.082764  2006        2
9   0.103519  2005        2
10 -0.048100  2004        2
11 -0.014992  2003        2
12  0.166187  1966        3
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your dataframe is called `df` and you have a nested dictionary of your country codes as shown below. Then you can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
country_code = {'Country': {'Australia':1, 'China':2, 'Greece':3, 'Japan':4}}

df = df.replace(country_code)
# alternatively df['Country'] = df['Country'].replace(country_code['Country'])    

df['Country'] = df['Country'].fillna(method='pad') # fills up the nans
```